# Implementing Face Detection from bitmap android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, face-detection

- Face Detection

I had a bitmap want to detect face from that bitmap in java . Any one have idea to get face from image .

Answer (score 4):

u can try this code to get a rectangle drawn around each face you detect in a bitmap image..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.media.FaceDetector;
import android.media.FaceDetector.Face;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class FaceDetection extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(new myView(this));
 }

 private class myView extends View {

  private int imageWidth, imageHeight;
  private int numberOfFace = 5;
  private FaceDetector myFaceDetect;
  private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;
  float myEyesDistance;
  int numberOfFaceDetected;

  Bitmap myBitmap;

  public myView(Context context) {
   super(context);

   BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
   myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     R.drawable.jennifer_lopez, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
   imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
   imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
   myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
   myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight,
     numberOfFace);
   numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

   canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

   Paint myPaint = new Paint();
   myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
   myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
    Face face = myFace[i];
    PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
    face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
    myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();

    canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance * 2),
      (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance * 2),
      (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance * 2),
      (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance * 2), myPaint);
   }
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: How much feasible is this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You have support for that in Android SDK. You should check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get face bitmap using following code

private Bitmap cropBitmap1(Bitmap bmp2, Face face)
        {

```
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        int x = (int) face.getPosition().x/2;
        int y = (int) face.getPosition().y/2;
        int width = (int) face.getWidth() / 2;
        int height = (int) face.getHeight() / 2;

        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2, x , y,width,height,mat,true);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```